# what's the meaning of " in a champagne mood"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I came across a quote from Franz Marc "We are staunch and true and in rather a champagne mood." , what's the meaning of Champagne mood? a celebration

Comment: Champagne is a celebratory drink.

Comment: Champagne is similarly used all over the world, I would think?  Although technically, wine makers can't call it "champagne" unless it's from that region of France.

Comment: Well, technically [winemakers can and do call it champagne or whatever they want](http://static.vinepair.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/california-champagne-header.jpg) unless the laws of their specific country prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

It means that they're in the mood for drinking champagne. They're probably going to celebrate something because champagne is an alcoholic drink people usually drink when they celebrate something special (for example, two people getting married, somebody's birthday, victory in a match, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Happiness is described as a champagne mood: the effervescence (=excitement) and the intoxication (=festive euphoria)... Vincent Cespedes is a french philosopher and wrote about it in his book => Magic study of happiness